# Azure Data Factory processing end when validation fails

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have developed a process to run a Stored process, only if there is a certain file. I used Validation to achieve this. The validation checks whether the file exists, if so, it starts the process. However, the issue is, if the file not exists it creates an error (Status comes as Error and the message is "Operation on target Check SRManifest Exists failed:"), even after i have added a Wait. What I wanted to happen is, if the file does not exist the process needs to be stopped. Appreciate if someone can help me to achieve. Below is the existing processes.[image]

Validation Settings as below:[image] Also, The properties are as below [image]

Comment: Can you show the settings of your 'Check SRMainfest' activity? In fact, it should be in process if the file not exists instead of throw out an error.

Comment: @BowmanZhu Thank you. Please see the above. I added the screen shots. Thanka

Comment: The error is by design. If your pipeline has an activity that face something like timeout, it will give to an error and the pipeline will be 'failed'. But the whole process has been down. The error is just tell you the validation dont find the file during the 30s timeout and want to to notice it. That doesn't mean your pipeline is wrong.

Comment: As long as any activity in the pipeline encounters a problem, the entire pipeline will be in a 'failed' state. The problem you are experiencing is a timeout problem. The activity did not find the file within 30s. This error is expected.

Comment: Hi, any update on this question? If you dont have more doubts, can you [mark my answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsESi.png) to end this question?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is no problem with your design.

I put a blob path that is not exist in the validation activity, and I also get this error. But if you go to see the monitor of the pipeline, you will found the wait activity is success:

[image]

> if the file does not exist the process needs to be stopped.

Your pipeline is finish. So the process is already stop.

There is no problem with your piping design. But ADF will definitely throw an error for a validation activity that encounters a timeout. Unless you do not reach the timeout 30 seconds that you setted, this error is expected, it is not your problem.